# Range of a unitary transformed orthogonal projection

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, transformation, orthogonality, projection

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space, $P$ an orthogonal projection in $X$ and $Q \in L(X)$ (i.e. $Q \colon X \to X$ is linear and continuous)
 a unitary linear transformation, i.e. $Q^*Q=Id_X= QQ^*$ ($Q^*$ denotes the Hilbert space adjoint of $Q$).
I have shown that 
$$\tilde{P} = QPQ^*$$ is an orthogonal projection. What can we say about the range of $\tilde{P}$?

Answer (score 0):

The range of $\tilde{P}$ is equal to $Q \mathrm{ran} (P) = \{ Qy : y \in \mathrm{ran}(P)  \},$ which you can prove simply by set inclusion. (For one of the directions you should insert $Q^* Q = I$ somewhere.)